Can your main wallet get drained if somebody knows the seed phrase of an extra account/wallet you created?
My entire Phantom wallet got drained a few days ago.
The person who stole from me knew the seed phrase of an extra wallet I created in the Phantom wallet app (with no money on it), but he stole all the money from my main wallet.
How is this possible? Two different wallets, two different seed phrases right?!

no it's 1 seed phrase but 2 different private keys, but one seed phrase can correspond to many wallets addresses / private keys. If you uninstall your phantom extension and install it again, when you add your seed phrase, it will give you access to all the accounts you created under this seed phrase
